# awk command syntax error

Tags: command-line, awk

```
$ awk '$2 - /^Tom$/ {print}' names.txt
```

I am trying to search for a file that has the 2nd field matching Tom.

But I am getting this error:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    $2 - /^Tom$/ >>>  { <<<
```

Comment: I don't see how it could cause the specific error that you have reported, but the regex comparison operator should be tilde (`~`) not minus (`-`). Although if you are testing for a literal match, `$2 == "Tom"` would be simpler.

Comment: Question, are you using non-english input language ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have syntax error. Should be

```
awk '$2 ~ /Tom/ {print}' names.txt
```

or

```
awk '$2 == "Tom" {print}' names.txt
```

Note that `{print}` is unnecessary. Awk will print lines for which matching condition is true automatically.

```
$ awk '$2 =="Tom"' input.txt                                                                                             
Edison, Tom

$ cat input.txt                                                                                                          
Washington, George
Edison, Tom
Tesla, Nik
```